# Foreign cannot be create due to #1046 - No database selected

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE fee
(
    payment_no int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    student_name varchar(255),
    student_class varchar(255),
    register_fee double,
    paid_fee double,
    balanced double, 
    monthly_fee double, 
    transport_fee double, 
    extra_fee double, 
    PRIMARY KEY (payment_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_name, student_class, register_date)
        REFERENCES kids(student_name,student_class,register_date)
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1046 - No database selected

Comment: Did you create database?